# How to use keycloak authentication for ejb remote client with wildfly elytron security?

Tags: ejb, wildfly, keycloak, sasl, elytron

I've some web application which authenticates on `Keycloak` and call `EJBs`. The security in `Wildfly` is configured with `Elytron` and the security context is propagated correctly between web and EJB.

Now I've to write a java client (desktop application) which have to call the same EJBs on the server using Wildfly http+remoting.
I suppose I need to configure `SASL` authentication against Keycloak on Wildfly, probably using `oauth` bearer token obtained by java client logging in with Keycloak.

I can't find any information about how to configure SASL with Keycloak on Wildfly. Does someone have some hit about that?